# PCA biplot of data subset

Tags: r, plot, pca, vegan

I'm trying to produce pca biplots for data subsets.
Within the same principal components environment I'd like to plot only subsets based on Moisture levels.

```
# Packages
library(vegan)

# Sample data
data(dune, dune.env)
dd <- cbind(dune.env, dune)

# Runnig PCA
pca1 <- rda(dd[, -c(1:5)], scale=T)

# Plot
plot(pca1, scaling=3)

# Now, instead the plot above, I'd like to get 5 different plots (one per dd$Moisture level) where I see the principal components scores but only for the subsets based on:
levels(dd$Moisture)
```

Many thanks in advance for any inputs!!

Comment: This seems related: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/188236.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment user1981275. It guide me  to  answer my own question (I hope it's correct! :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are somewhat easier ways to do these faceted plots with `ordixyplot()` in **vegan** or the **ggvegan** package (currently alpha so simple things sometimes need to be done by hand).

### Example

```
# Packages
library("vegan")
library("ggvegan")

# Sample data
data(dune, dune.env)

# PCA
pca1 <- rda(dune, scale = TRUE)
```

### The *ggvegan* version

As I said, you need to do a bit of munging by hand and the moment, but you get the legend for free with ggplot.

```
## use fortify method to extract scores in ggplot-friendly format
scrs <- fortify(pca1, scaling = 3)
## take only site scores for this
scrs <- with(scrs, scrs[Score == "sites", ])
## add on Moisture variable
scrs <- cbind(scrs, Moisture = dune.env$Moisture)

## for all points on one plot, Moisture coded by colour
plt <- ggplot(scrs, aes(x = Dim1, y = Dim2, colour = Moisture)) + 
         geom_point() + coord_fixed()
plt

## to facet that plot into multiple panels
plt + facet_wrap( ~ Moisture)
```

### The `ordixyplot()` version

More of the work is canned within `ordixyplot()` than with the **ggvegan** version, but you have to work a little harder to add the key (legend) and I can never remember how to do this with Lattice.

```
## Single plot
ordixyplot(pca1, data = dune.env, formula = PC1 ~ PC2, group = Moisture)

## Facet plot
ordixyplot(pca1, data = dune.env, formula = PC1 ~ PC2 | Moisture)
```

### Base graphics

For base graphics there is an easier version to colour the points on a single plot. One version is

```
scrs <- scores(pca1, display = "sites")
cols <- c("red","green","blue","orange","purple")
plot(scrs[,1], scrs[,2], pch = 19, 
     col = cols[as.numeric(as.character(dune.env$Moisture))])
legend("topright", legend = 1:5, title = "Moisture", pch = 19, 
       col = cols, bty = "n")
```

You can find out more about doing the plots this way using base graphics in a blog [post](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/11/customising-vegans-ordination-plots/) that I wrote a few years ago.

Comment: @ Gavin Simpson. Thanks a lot for your input, really useful! Also for the post in your blog, I had already been working with it today, it's great! Despite the colours are helpful I'd actually like to have, let's say, each colour in a different plot but all within the same PC environment. I cannot install ggvegan due to my R version.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Packages
library("vegan")

# Preparing data
data(dune, dune.env)
dd <- cbind(dune.env, dune)
# Order data frame based on dd$Moisture
dd <- dd[order(dd$Moisture),]
str(dd)

# Runnig PCA
pca1 <- rda(dd[, -c(1:5)], scale=T)

# Plot
biplot(pca1, scaling=3, type = c("text", "points"))

# I need to get 5 different plots (one per dd$Moisture level)
# grab the scores on axes required
site.scr <- scores(pca1, display = "sites", scaling = 3) # x
spp.scr <- scores(pca1, display = "species", scaling = 3) # y

## generate x,y lims
xlims <- range(site.scr[,1], spp.scr[,1])
ylims <- range(site.scr[,2], spp.scr[,2])

## plot what you want, but leave out sites
biplot(mod, display = "species", 
       xlim=xlims, ylim=ylims, 
       scaling = 3)

## now add in scores as you want, to simulate we plot:
# Moisture - All together but can be in independetn plots
points(site.scr[1:7,], col = "blue", pch = 2)
points(site.scr[8:11,], col = "green", pch = 2)
points(site.scr[0:0,], col = "orange", pch = 2) # Level 3 not present
points(site.scr[12:13,], col = "grey", pch = 2)
points(site.scr[14:20,], col = "black", pch = 2)
```